# Help with $Hom_{R}(A,B)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Show that the set of the R-homomorphism  $A\rightarrow B$  with factorization through an injective module is an subgroup of $Hom_{R}(A,B)$.

It's a question from  my last test in  abstract algebra, that I can't solve.

Comment: If $f:A\to B$ factors through the injective $I$, and $g:A\to B$ factors through the injective $J$, what injective does $f+g$ factor through? Remember that the direct product of two injective modules is injective...

Comment: Gracias Mariano, gran ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: This just follows from the fact that a direct sum of two injective modules is injective.